# OrientDB Edge Query

Tags: graph, time-series, orientdb

I have a time series model that uses linkmaps and it connects to another vertex event by an edge called registered_events

year->month->day->hour -> **edge** (registered_events) -> event

I am trying to expand the edge to display the events but I am having no success. The query is

```
select expand(month[12].day[3].hour[23]).out('registered_event') from Year where year = 2015
```

The output of the query is below

```
METADATA    PROPERTIES  OUT @rid @version @class hour registered_events

                        #24:7   41    Hour  23    #27:0 #27:1 #27:2 #27:3 #27:4 #27:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
 select expand(month[12].day[3].hour[23].out('registered_event')) from Year where year = 2015
```

If you are using v 2.1 RCx I suggest you to use UNWIND operator instead of expand:

```
 select month[12].day[3].hour[23].out('registered_event') as events from Year where year = 2015 UNWIND events
```

Comment: The first option returned an empty resultset. The second option says invalid keyword unwind. I am using dev enterprise 2.1 rc1

Answer (score 0):

The Hour Vertex has not been extended with superclass V.

Once I altered the class to extend v and changed the query to

```
select expand(month[12].day[3].hour[23]).out('registered_event') from Year where year = 2015
```

it worked